# Is this graph theory paper in German translated into English?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, translation

I recently read such a paper and want to understand the proof idea of ​​this article. However since it is in German and  I have not studied German before, I'd like to ask whether this paper has an English version. Or is there a good translation tool available?

- Schumacher V H. **Zur Struktur 1‐planarer Graphen**[J]. Mathematische
  Nachrichten, 1986, 125(1): 291-300.
  doi:https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.19861250122

Comment: You may try to translate it through deepl.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: Just in case there will be questions left for you... I'm a native speaker and understand some graph theory

Comment: @Hermann Gruber Thank you very much. I'm going to try to translate first. If there's a native speaker who can help translate.That's a real help！